# How can I keep the data after hiding it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-chartjs

I have three graphics using react-chartjs-2, which are added certain values ​​using a modal.

The problem that happens to me is that I have a button that hides the graphics, but when I hide it and display them again the values ​​that are in the graphics are deleted and I don't know how to recover it.

Someone knows how to keep the data, here is the code.

[code in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-trvk2u)

Comment: Notice that the Link failed.

Comment: It is already fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `chart.js` line 39, `dataset.data = props.entries;` changes `props.entries` to []. So we have to generate a copy to `entries`.

So, add `.slice()` to file `paper.js` line 39.

```
<Chart entries={entries.slice()} />
```